# When did Application restart?

Tags: android, android-activity, mount

Sometimes I see my app in DDMS restart.As I see it's process id changed.(I'm not sure that,because I don't write log for application oncreate.)

That behaviour ofen happened when I mount SDCard to share USB mode.I'd like to see what happend after mount in my application.So I debug my App,but unfortunately.When mount to share USB mode,application's process id changed and debug been auto stopped.

Why?What happened?What's the strategy for android handle application restart?

And there is another question.Why does sometimes an activity occur an error,thrown an exception dialog,and restart it.Sometimes the android platform just kill the activity and exit.

Maybe it's not a very useful question for develop.But I'm really missing,I want to know the answer.Please help me,friends.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I used to get into similar cases like yours, what I did to handle and detect is like:

 1. Check Device: sometimes devices mal-functioning really cause problems, a bad USB cable will really do restart Android/application.
 
 2. Collect Log: after application restarts, just collect the log from system/event/radio/dumpstate... remember the time when app started to restart then check in log files to look for the causes.

Well, that's my experiences and it works, not in all situations but most of the time.